# Adding new lines in XML file

Tags: xml, awk, sed

I have a bunch of XML-files that all start with the XML-declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

After the final ">" it just goes on directly with the start of the following tag - like this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tag>`

I would like to split it there to make a new line followed by another new line. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
New line
New line
<tag>
```

How could this be done?

Many thanks in advance:-)

/Paul

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
AMD$ sed 's/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>/&\n\n\n/' File
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<tag>
```

Just replace the pattern `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` with the same pattern followed by `3` newlines (this will create `2` newlines before `<tag>`.

Use `sed -i.bak 's/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>/&\n\n\n/' File` for inplace substitution.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Huge thanks. I wrapped it in a for loop then I was done.

Answer (score 0):

based on your definition (start with) and content

```
sed '1 {
   /<[?]xml/ {
      s/<tag>//
      a \
new line 1 (whatever also just a \n like "new line 2") \
\
<tag>
      }
   }' YourFile
```

- Adapt the line using a *append* with free text (new line are `\` char) with a bit of security (take only 1st line and starting with `?xml`)
- use `-i` for inline modification on GNU sed